# Modelling a lavender flower?

Tags: modeling

I would like to model a lavender flower:
[image]

However, I don't know how to apply the blossoms properly. I guess they need to have a different rotation, need to look like they grew naturally (so in this kinda ring-like constellation) and those little leaves under the blossoms are also confusing me.

Any help?

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of what you have so far or where you are stuck? It would be easier to help you fix it.

Comment: I didn't even start it because I don't even know where to start honestly